# Hotkey to transfer all items easily

Tags: starbound

Currently I know that the game has a button on a chest to transfer all items from chest to you.

(As Shown in this picture)
[image: Image of button]

But I generally prefer using Hotkeys/Shortcuts rather than pressing buttons with a mouse.

What is the hotkey/shortcut key that I can press on my keyboard to transfer all items from the chest to my character? (And vice-versa if possible)

Answer (score 2):

Right now it is not possible. Game is still in active developing so maybe we get such feature later. Mod does not exist as well. Don't think you are only one, it pissing me off too.